# How can I manage the background image of a slider based on the featured image of a page?

Tags: plugins, images

I have various pages with sliders and I need to give the client the ability to change those images in the sliders in a easy way.

I thought on setting the slider image background based on each page featured image to make it easy to give a front-end solution for the client to have this control since I didn't make the theme.

Has anyone ever had this problem? Any solutions or ideas are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who wondered the same thing as me, here is a solution:

I've got various references along the way to solve this so sorry for the lack of some links. Most of the solution don't come from me, I merely picked some pieces and put it together.

I used Revolution Slider and OptionTree to create the slider and the front-end options for the client to use.

You'll need two pieces of code on your "functions.php":

```
//Function to get id based on slug/link
function get_attachment_id_from_src ($image_src) {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE guid='$image_src'";
    $id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
    return $id;
}

// Define Featured Image based on OptionTree Theme Options
function defineFeaturedImage () {
    wp_reset_query();

    if (is_page()) {
        $page_id = get_the_ID();

        $post_slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() );

        if (is_page('/')) {
            $optiontree_id = 'bg_home';

        } elseif (is_page('firstpage')) {
            $optiontree_id = 'bg_firstpage';

        }
    }

    $url_featured = ot_get_option( $optiontree_id );

    $featured_id = get_attachment_id_from_src( $url_featured );

    if (!empty($page_id) && !empty($featured_id)) {

        set_post_thumbnail( $page_id, $featured_id );

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'defineFeaturedImage', 10, 3);
```

After that you just need to configure OptionTree for the options like the ones above with the **ID** just like each page you need to change (you need to add more `elseif` to change more pages, this code you still need to add one at a time).
On Revolution Slider you need to configure the slider as any of the ["Post Based" sliders type](https://www.themepunch.com/revslider-doc/post-based-slider/).

With that, revolution slider will change its background (if you set it to based on the post/page featured image), and even add any data from wordpress in the slider based on post/page.

So you just use this code above and OptionTree to control the featured image on each post/page.

Hope it helps someone :)